# Converting a matrix into a single value in Keras

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a Keras model where the input is a matrix, and I want the output to be a single value. However, I'm encountering an issue with the code where it throws an error related to the number of samples in the input and output arrays.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Input (matrix)
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
              [2, 3, 4, 5],
              [3, 4, 5, 6],
              [4, 5, 6, 7],
              [5, 6, 7, 8]])

# Output (single value)
Y = np.array([-1])

# Creating model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

# Compiling
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Training
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=1)

# Predictions
new_data = np.array([[6, 7, 8, 9]])
pred = model.predict(new_data)
print("Prediction:", pred)
```

I'm receiving the following error message: "x sizes: 5, y sizes: 1. Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples." I understand that the issue is related to the number of samples in the input and output arrays.

My goal is to convert the matrix input into a single value as the output. How can I modify the code to achieve this?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want the network to make a prediction for matrices of different shapes (that is, one value per given matrix)? Or do you want a prediction for each row of the matrix?